# How to delay ExtJS store load event in Ext.Ajax BeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, extjs

How can I delay the loading of the extjs stores or suspend & resume later?

I have ExtJS stores that are set with autoLoad = true and it will be called when the application launch. These stores are configured to point to a servlet which will check for a user session. It will throw exception if there is no user session. How can I delay the stores from going to the servlet side before user login?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you don't want them to automatically load when the instance is created, don't create it with `autoLoad: true`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - right. Or you can load the UserData onBeforeLaunch (the mainview is loaded right at the end of onBeforeLaunch, when you call this.callParent(arguments)). Or you can add the store to a viewModel and add the view only after you received the UserData